# How do I cancel an AJAX request that has already been initiated using native javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Can someone please tell me how I can cancel an Ajax request that is in native javacript and use the very same native javascript to cancel the request.

I am aiming to provide a script I am writing with a background task to check if a request has completed in a specific time and if it hasn't then to cancel the request should it still be waiting.

So all scripts I have seen are tagged as Javascript but are in fact JQuery, something that I am not interested in at all and would prefer to be writing my own methods without using something that I have no interest in using.

So a little bit of help is appreciated.

so do I use a command like

```
xmlHTTP.cancel();
```

or

```
xmlHTTP.kill();
```

I know that JQuery has abort but this is an alias of a native command, so a pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: the native method is abort... jquery's abort call likely just calls the method on [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: no code needed, I just wanted to know what the proper command was to cancel an ongoing AJAX request.

The reason being that if the server is taking too long to respond, the process is canceled and then trys again at a later date, currently with the question answered, the current AJAX script I am making is working just fine.

This is a personal project and will be based on a LAN at my home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) - it's there in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was a case of every query I made with google turned up JQuery and abort() appeared on the face of it to be part of JQuery.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you to use jQuery and use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method to init XHR Call. You can use abort method to kill existing XHR calls.

```
var xhr = null;

if (xhr != null) {
    xhr.abort();    //If xhr is not null then abort before init new XHR call
}

var xhr = jQuery.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "http://www.example.org/ajax.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            param1: "",
            param2: ""
        },
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
            //TODO
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //TODO
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //TODO
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            //TODO

            xhr = null;    //nulify xhr once we finish XHR call
        }
    });
```

Comment: -1: the OP expressly mentions, twice, that they don't want the jQuery version of this.